# Is there a way to list this dictionary into the front end (displayed in the browser) using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a dictionary in which I want to list on the front end or make it visible in the broswer:

```js
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to display the values in the browswer itself using react?

Comment: Yes, send the list as JSON to the client, the client can get the response using something like fetch, and then React can render it.

Comment: Once you have the data on the client side you can use `.map()` on your array to create an array of JSX elements, that you can display

Comment: Are you looking for [<pre>: The Preformatted Text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) format?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the array in the browser, you could use the [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag and the set the text within it to `JSON.stringify(array, null, 4)`. This will create a JSON with 4 spaces as indentations

```js
const array = [{userId:1,id:1,title:"quidem molestiae enim"},{userId:1,id:2,title:"sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"},{userId:1,id:3,title:"omnis laborum odio"}];

function Example({ array }) {
  return (
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(array, null, 4)}</pre>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example array={array} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have the -Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' error. This has been plaguing me too for a while and Im not sure how to solve this.

Comment: @mundus you need to fix your setup. `<Example />` is invalid javascript. It needs to transpiled to javascript from jsx. Please follow the Create React App and other documentation from React site.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign ata from file or api to state and then display as a list using map feature

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    
    
    class Main extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount = async () => {
        
        const data = await fetch ("https://api.dictionary.data.com")
        this.setState({dictionaryData:data})
    
      };
    
    
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          dictionaryData: []
        };
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div style = {styles.Container}  >
              
               {this.state.dictionaryData.map(Item => {
                         return (
                           <div style = {Styles.Item} >
                                 <p> {Item.title} </p>
                           </div>
                 )
}}
    
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Main;
    
    let styles = {
        Item: {
        borderStyle: "none",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        color: "magenta",
        cursor: "pointer",
        outlineColor: "cyan",
        borderRadius: 50,
      
      },
      Container: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: '20%',
        left: '20%',
        width: '50%',
        height: '80%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection:'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
      }
    };
```